# How would I plot a horizontal line on the chart with a Specific time like New york time and have a labels?

Tags: plot, time, pine-script-v5

So I'm trying to figure out how to plot lines on a chart and have them appear at the daily high but at a specific time like new York time 5p im also trying to add labels to these lines now if I knew how to post my whole code I would have but Im new here and it wont let me p.s ( I only want the previous day High and lows and previous week) any help is highly appreciated

I cant post my code so I cant show What I have been trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your chart is in a timeframe lower than 1 DAY, you can use :

```
DayHigh = request.security(syminfo.ticker, "D", high)
plot(DayHigh)
```